# togglebutton failing in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to show different html body on same tab having two toggle buttons. I have two toggle buttons with one as pre-configured. I want to show different html on two different buttons, for doing this I have added one functions named getBody for rendering html.

But I'm not getting how to call this function with certain condition in toggle button. For doing this I have added one variable flag. And I am not getting how to use toggle button . It should be something like EbLog will be by default pre-configured and after that one can use CloudLog.

```
export default class ResourceLog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      streamData: {},
      streamMessage: "",
      interval: 5000,
      showDatePicker: false,
      selectionConfigs: [
        {
          name: "1 Hr",
          cssClass: "btn btn-info btn-sm",
          duration: 300,
          startTime: -1,
          endTime: -1,
          diff: 3600
        },
        {
          name: "3 Hr",
          cssClass: "btn btn-info btn-sm",
          duration: 300,
          startTime: -1,
          endTime: -1,
          diff: 10800
        }
      ],
      params: {},
      show: "EbLog",
      value: 1
    };
  }
  streamLogs = () => {
    if (this.props.resource.status === "ACTIVE") {
      this.setState({ streamMessage: "loading logs.." });
      axios.instance
        .get("api/resources/" + this.props.resource.id + "/log/stream")
        .then(resp => {
          this.setState({ streamData: resp.data, streamMessage: "" });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.setState({ streamMessage: "" });
          NotificationManager.error("unable to fetch logs");
        });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        streamMessage: "Resource is not Active cannot fetch/stream logs..."
      });
    }
  };
  onCloud = () => {
    let endTime = this.state.params.endTime;
    if (endTime === -1) {
      endTime = new Date().getTime();
    }
    let startTime = this.state.params.startTime;
    if (startTime === -1) {
      startTime = endTime - this.state.params.diff * 1000;
    }

    let filter = this.state.params.duration;
    if (filter === -1) {
      filter = "";
    }

    let params = Object.assign(
      {},
      { startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime, filter: period }
    );

    this.setState({ streamMessage: "loading stats.." });
    axios.instance
      .get("api/resources/" + this.props.resource.id + "/cloud/log", {
        params: params
      })
      .then(resp => {
        this.setState({ data: resp.data, streamMessage: "" });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        NotificationManager.error(`Failed to fetch stats-`, "Error");
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        //<button style={edit} onClick={this.streamLogs}>
          EbLog
        </button>
        //<button style={edit} onClick={this.onCloud}>
          CloudLog
        </button>
        <ButtonToolbar>
          <ToggleButtonGroup type="checkbox" defaultValue={[1]}>
            <ToggleButton value={1}>EBLog</ToggleButton>
            {}
            <ToggleButton value={2}>CloudLog</ToggleButton>
          </ToggleButtonGroup>
        </ButtonToolbar>
        {this.getBody()}
      </div>
    );
  }

  getBody = () => {
    if (this.state.show == "EbLog") {
      return (
        <div className="row" style={{ margin: "15px" }}>
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <h3 style={{ display: "inline" }}>
              Logs
              <span
                style={{ marginLeft: "10px", cursor: "pointer" }}
                title={"Download"}
              >
                <a
                  target="_blank"
                  href={`api/resources/${this.props.resource.id}/log`}
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-download" />
                </a>
              </span>
              <span
                style={{ marginLeft: "10px", cursor: "pointer" }}
                title={"Refresh"}
              >
                <i onClick={this.streamLogs} className="fa fa-refresh" />
              </span>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div className="clearfix" />
          <br />
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <div>{this.state.streamMessage}</div>
            {mapObject(this.state.streamData, (k, v) => (
              <div>
                <pre>{v.join("\n")}</pre>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else if (this.state.show == "CloudLog") {
      return (
        <div className="row" style={{ margin: "20px", textAlign: "center" }}>
          <div>
            <span
              className={this.state.selectionConfigs[0].cssClass}
              onClick={() =>
                this.updateStatsConf(this.state.selectionConfigs[0])
              }
            >
              {this.state.selectionConfigs[0].name}
            </span>
            <span
              style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
              className={this.state.selectionConfigs[1].cssClass}
              onClick={() =>
                this.updateStatsConf(this.state.selectionConfigs[1])
              }
            >
              {this.state.selectionConfigs[1].name}
            </span>
            <span
              style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
              className={this.state.selectionConfigs[2].cssClass}
              onClick={() =>
                this.updateStatsConf(this.state.selectionConfigs[2])
              }
            >
              {this.state.selectionConfigs[2].name}
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="row" style={{ margin: "20px" }}>
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <div>{this.state.streamMessage}</div>
              {mapObject(this.state.streamData, (k, v) => (
                <div>
                  <pre>{v.join("\n")}</pre>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      <h1> please click a Button </h1>;
    }
  };
}
```

Please refer [this](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/button-group/) link. I have used this link as reference for creating ToggleButton under section Controlled

Comment: the problem is not clear,did you want to change the view according to the toggle button click ?

Comment: yes i want to change the view on clicking on toggle button

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you need to create a simple method to change state on click. Say something like;

```
toggleButton = (text) => {
    this.setState({show: text});
}
```

And then use onClick attribute in your ToggleButton element;

```
<ToggleButtonGroup type="checkbox" defaultValue={[1]}>
  <ToggleButton value={1} onClick={this.toggleButton.bind(this, "EbLog")}>EBLog</ToggleButton>
    {}
  <ToggleButton value={2} onClick={this.toggleButton.bind(this, "CloudLog")}>CloudLog</ToggleButton>
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

Comment: Added but not able to call onCloud function i've done this:<ToggleButton value={1} onClick={this.toggleButton.bind(this.streamLogs, "EbLog")}>EBLog</ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value={2} onClick={this.toggleButton.bind(this.onCloud, "CloudLog")}>CloudLog</ToggleButton>

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood from the problem, please refer the following example to render different views according to toggle button click.
The toggle button should be as follows

```
<ToggleButton onClick = {this.toggleButton}/>
```

The method should update the state

```
  toggleButton(value){
        value ? this.setState(show:'CloudLog') : this.setState(show:'EbLog')
    }
```

The render method can be as

```
render() {
   return(
    this.state.show ==='CloudLog' ? <div>View 1</div> : <div>View 2</div>
)
}
```